# Clear all Contents

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to write code that will completely wipe cell contents in a workbook.

I'd like to have two similar `Subs`: One `Sub` to clear all contents and another `Sub` to clear all contents starting from 2nd row to the last row.

I am using following code but it's returning an error:

```
Sub Populate_RA_Sheet()
    '
    ' Populate_RA_Sheet Macro
    '
    RA_Sheet(2).Cells.ClearContents
    '
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7):

Let's say the name of the sheet is `Sheet1` Then

> One code clear all content

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.ClearContents
```

> and other code clear all contents starting from 2nd row till the last row whatever it is.

You can find the last row and then clear the contents. But why would you want to do that? Simply Clear `ALL` rows after the 2nd Row?

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Rows("2:" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents
End With
```

If you **still** want to clear all contents starting from 2nd row till the last row then see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) on how to find the last row and once you get the last row then simply use this

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Rows("2:" & LastRow).ClearContents
End With
```

**Note**:

1. The above code will fail if say Cell `A1:A2` is merged. So be careful of that :)
2. This code will clear the cells but not delete any shapes/formatting. You will have to handle it separately.